# Zipping a file while working in a different directory

Tags: linux, command-line, zip

I'm trying to zip a file from the command line while I'm currently working in a different directory than that file is in.

The file is located at `/home/one/file.txt`

The present working directory is `/home/two/`

When I use the command `zip /home/one/file.zip /home/one/file.txt`, the zip file is created in the correct directory (`/home/one`), but the contents of the zip file are `/home/one/file.txt`. I want for the zip file to only contain `file.txt`.

What's the command to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Zip is archiving file structure relative to the current directory. To override it you will need a `-j` flag. As per man pages:

```
-j --junk-paths
Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not store directory names. By default, zip will store the full path (relative to the current directory).
```

EDIT: That means `-j` omits directory names so only files will be compressed. So your example (with working directory in /home/two) would look something like this:

```
zip -j ../one/file.zip ../one/file.txt
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused how using -j works. When I use the command `zip -j /home/one/file.zip /home/one/file.txt`, I'm getting `zip error: Nothing to do!`

Comment: @XtevensChannel I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use this command :

```
cd /home/one; zip /home/two/file.zip file.txt
```

You could use `pushd` instead of `cd` so you may come back to the same folder
with `popd`. You could also create a script for it.